# Unable to create AWS Lambda Deployment Package for ipopt, pyomo, cython

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, virtualenv, ipopt

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda Deployment Package, so I can use it as an AWS Lambda Layer.  Specifically, I'm trying to use the ipopt sovler, in conjuction with the pyomo and cython.  I can get the pyomo packaged without issue, but when I try to pip install ipopt for the package I get an error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rir_unvz\\ipopt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rir_unvz\\ipopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d1o_oqjy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python36\Include\ipopt'
         cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rir_unvz\ipopt\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ipopt
    copying ipopt\ipopt_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ipopt
    copying ipopt\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ipopt
    copying ipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ipopt
    running build_ext
    skipping 'src\cyipopt.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'ipopt.cyipopt' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iinclude_mt/coin -Ic:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python36\include -Ic:\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc\cyipopt.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src\cyipopt.obj
    cyipopt.c
    c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    src\cyipopt.c(569): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'IpStdCInterface.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rir_unvz\\ipopt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rir_unvz\\ipopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d1o_oqjy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python36\Include\ipopt' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am trying to run the pyomo/ipopt package in an AWS lambda function. This package isn't in the SDK, so I've read that I'll have to compile the dependencies into a zip, and then upload the zip into the lambda function.

I've done some research and tried out the links below, but when I try to pip install ipopt I get error messages - I'm on a Windows box, but I've also tried it on the Linux EC2 instance

Appreciate the help!

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/

[Unable to install cvxpy into virtualenv for AWS lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647020/unable-to-install-cvxpy-into-virtualenv-for-aws-lambda/58655323#58655323)

https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-set-up-layers-python-in-aws-lambda-functions-1355519c11ed

https://medium.com/@qtangs/creating-new-aws-lambda-layer-for-python-pandas-library-348b126e9f3e

https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

[AWS Lambda - unable to import module 'lambda_function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734744/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**, here is the working lambda deployment package that's compatible with Python 3.6 runtime. [[gdrive download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eNtZmEuhiquiVRQb5x1NzcMRd2RDzggz/view?usp=sharing)]

It turns out it's super tricky to pack everything needed into one zip. I spent quite a while (several hours) manually copying library files over. Here are the steps that I took to generate this package.

1. Spin up a local lambda Python 3.6 runtime docker container

```
docker run -it --rm lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 bash
```

2. Pip install all the dependencies into a local directory

```
mkdir ipopt-lib
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/ipopt-lib
pip install Cython numpy -t ipopt-lib/
```

3. Followed the [official guide](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html) to build and install Ipopt from source code

```
yum install lapack-devel
git clone https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt.git
cd Ipopt
IPOPTDIR=`pwd`
mkdir $IPOPTDIR/build
cd $IPOPTDIR/build
$IPOPTDIR/configure
make
make install
```

4. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig pip install ipopt -t ipopt-lib/`
5. Manually copying all the library files over

```
cp -t ~/ipopt-lib/ /usr/local/lib/lib*
cp -t ~/ipopt-lib/ /usr/lib64/libblas.so* /usr/lib64/liblapack*
cp -t ~/ipopt-lib/ /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3*
cp -t ~/ipopt-lib/ /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so*
cp -t ~/ipopt-lib/ /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0*
```

6. Zipping all together

```
cd ~/ipopt-lib
zip -r /root/ipopt-lib.zip *
```

7. Copy to the host machine

```
docker cp <CONTAINER_ID>:/root/ipopt-lib.zip ~/Downloads/
```

#### Here are all the Python packages available in this deployment package (including the default ones installed in the runtime):

```sh
$ pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
arrow==0.15.5
attrs==19.3.0
aws-lambda-builders==0.8.0
aws-sam-cli==0.47.0
aws-sam-translator==1.22.0
awscli==1.18.41
binaryornot==0.4.4
boto3==1.12.41
botocore==1.15.41
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
chevron==0.13.1
click==7.1.1
colorama==0.4.3
cookiecutter==1.6.0
Cython==0.29.17
dateparser==0.7.4
distlib==0.3.0
docker==4.2.0
docutils==0.15.2
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.0.4
future==0.18.2
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
importlib-resources==1.4.0
ipopt==0.1.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jinja2-time==0.2.0
jmespath==0.9.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.18.3
pipenv==2018.11.26
poyo==0.5.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2020.4.4
requests==2.22.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.3.3
serverlessrepo==0.1.9
six==1.14.0
tomlkit==0.5.8
tzlocal==2.0.0
urllib3==1.25.8
virtualenv==20.0.18
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
websocket-client==0.57.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
whichcraft==0.6.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

#### Testing on lambda using Python 3.6 runtime

```
import sys
try:
    sys.path.index('/opt')
except ValueError:
    sys.path.append('/opt')
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/opt'
import json
import numpy
import ipopt


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(numpy.__version__)
    print(ipopt.__version__)
```

#### Result

```
Response:
null

Request ID:
"9bd9fd88-d340-4976-a954-8a727e173933"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 9bd9fd88-d340-4976-a954-8a727e173933 Version: $LATEST
1.18.3
0.1.9
END RequestId: 9bd9fd88-d340-4976-a954-8a727e173933
REPORT RequestId: 9bd9fd88-d340-4976-a954-8a727e173933  Duration: 0.45 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB  Init Duration: 343.99 ms
```

### Cheers!