# Failed building wheel for scs and cvxpy on amazon linux2

Tags: python, pip, cvxpy, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to create an AWS lambda layer for cvxpy, following [Rineesh Konaparthi's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647020/unable-to-install-cvxpy-into-virtualenv-for-aws-lambda).  I run to error when run pip install cvxpy:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: scs
  Building wheel for scs (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpkotzc_4k
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nh7lbi32/scs_2bbc38691e14434ebce20960b3331d42
  Complete output (68 lines):
  Namespace(blas64=False, extraverbose=False, float32=False, gpu=False, gpu_atrans=True, int32=False, scs=False)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/scs
  copying src/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/scs
  running build_ext
  /tmp/pip-build-env-xmfc085b/overlay/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    self.calc_info()
  /tmp/pip-build-env-xmfc085b/overlay/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  /tmp/pip-build-env-xmfc085b/overlay/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  /tmp/pip-build-env-xmfc085b/overlay/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
  /tmp/pip-build-env-xmfc085b/overlay/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
  blas_mkl_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  blis_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  openblas_info:
      libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  blas_opt_info:
      libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  lapack_mkl_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  lapack_opt_info:
      libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  {}
  {}
  error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYTHON -DCTRLC=1 -DDLONG=1 -DCOPYAMATRIX -Iscs/include -Iscs/linsys -Iscs/linsys/cpu/direct/ -Iscs/linsys/external/amd -Iscs/linsys/external/dqlql -I/tmp/pip-build-env-xmfc085b/overlay/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/scsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/scsmodule.o -O3" failed with exit status 127
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: **Failed building wheel for scs**
   Failed to build scs
   ERROR: Could not build wheels for scs which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Run pip install scs end with the same error.  The following is the information of the Python and pip.

AMI: Amazon Linux2

Python 3.7.10

pip 21.2.4 from /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Does anyone have any idea how to get it work or know an existing lambda layer that support cvxpy?

Comment: can you try this - `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` ?

Comment: @a11apurva tried it, same error.

Comment: Do you have numpy and scipy installed? if so, with which BLAs?

Comment: @Roim numpy-1.21.2 and scipy-1.7.1 installed successfully. verified import numpy as np works in Lambda function. run "locate libblas.so" returns nothing. So I guess no BALs lib installed.