# How to resolve AWS Lambda unable to import module error message?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library

I followed the steps in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItE6MAZaiJY) to create a virtual environment and zip the dependencies along with my code.

My code:

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError, ClientError
from PIL import Image
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

def get_img_list():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='imagesforgreendub',
    Prefix='photo_test/',
    )

    for val in response['Contents']:
        if val['Key'] != 'photo_test/':
            temp = val['Key']
            img_name = temp.split('/')
            print(img_name)
            if img_name[1] != '':
                thumb_name = 'thumb_' + str(img_name[1])
                print(thumb_name, img_name[1])
                img = image_from_s3('imagesforgreendub', val['Key'])
                img_thumb(img, thumb_name)

def image_from_s3(bucket_name, key):

    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
    image = bucket.Object(key)
    img_data = image.get().get('Body').read()

    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
def img_thumb(img, thumb_name):
    MAX_SIZE = (100, 100)
    img.thumbnail(MAX_SIZE)
    img.save('local_img.jpg')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file('local_img.jpg', 'imagesforgreendub', '%s/%s' % ('thumbs', thumb_name))
```

The handler name is `lambda_function.get_img_list` (get_img_list() is the first function that should run).

I read on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734744/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function) that the local libraries are compiled for the local machine architecture (I am using Windows 10 and Powershell).

The [github link](https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages/tree/master/lambda_packages) given in the aforementioned thread for lambda packages has Pillow for Python 2.7 and I am using 3.8.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be of assistance: [Sample Amazon S3 Function Code - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python). It is a walkthrough that packages up Pillow. You might also benefit from [Installing Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).