# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'joblib'

Tags: python, deployment, aws-lambda, dependencies

I wrote a AWS *lambda function* and got this error:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'joblib'",
```

I imported `joblib` in the header of my `lambda_function.py` file:

```
import boto3
import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import io
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import awswrangler as wr
```

Anyway around this error?

Comment: Can similar question & answer help you: [AWS Lambda - unable to import module 'lambda_function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734744/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function#49841953) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lambda Layer

AWS lambda wraps dependencies in what they call "layers". An AWS *lambda layer* is essentially a `.zip` file containing all the packages your lambda function will need (required imports).

See the AWS documentation, section [Creating and sharing Lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html), for how to create and deploy a layer.

#### Adding a module to an existing layer

If you are using an existing layer, then you need to add `joblib` to it, otherwise, you will probably encounter errors when trying to import all those other libraries too.

---

Absent any other code, there's not much more I can offer.

Comment: Brief pin-pointing answer! I improved the formatting slightly to make it shine. Hope you don't mind ️